# Trying to get images to fit entire column/row using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get three images to cumulatively take up an entire bootstrap row (effectively each taking up a column that spans 4). However, my code right now has them leaving gaps in between, and on either side. I've attached a screenshot of the problem, with the ideal solution to have the images take up the entire space without leaving any gaps. Below is the relevant html:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <image class="img-responsive" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/duocsoiqy/image/upload/v1500928572/Waterloo_Image_abjgbc.png" style="max-height:100%;width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <image class="img-responsive" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/duocsoiqy/image/upload/v1500928930/New_York_Image_ke8tya.png" style="max-height:100%;width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <image class="img-responsive" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/duocsoiqy/image/upload/v1500929276/Columbus_Image_t7oren.png" style="max-height:100%;width:100%">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Screenshot of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gevzN.jpg)

Comment: cols have padding. Either you remove the padding (properly through sass or less) or you put them as background of the div, or you don't use row/cols for that bit of your site

Comment: that is the default gutter. set the padding to 0 for them .somenamespace .col-md-4{ padding: 0;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap columns have default right and left padding of 15px.  Inspect the columns in devtools and you will see it.  You need to over ride it with your own custom css.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/hhzbxrbf/

```css
.col-md-4 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <image class="img-responsive" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/duocsoiqy/image/upload/v1500928572/Waterloo_Image_abjgbc.png" style="max-height:100%;width:100%" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <image class="img-responsive" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/duocsoiqy/image/upload/v1500928930/New_York_Image_ke8tya.png" style="max-height:100%;width:100%" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <image class="img-responsive" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/duocsoiqy/image/upload/v1500929276/Columbus_Image_t7oren.png" style="max-height:100%;width:100%" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```